# Procedure or function 'spAddEmployee' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My create form need to get access from stored procedure, when I ran the application I am getting this error:

> Procedure or function 'spAddEmployee' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied

C# code:

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AddEmployee"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spAddEmployee", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    con.Open();

    SqlParameter paramname = new SqlParameter();
    paramname.ParameterName = "@Name";
    paramname.Value = employee.Name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramname);

    SqlParameter paramgender = new SqlParameter();
    paramname.ParameterName = "@gender";
    paramname.Value = employee.Gender;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramgender);

    SqlParameter paramcity = new SqlParameter();
    paramname.ParameterName = "@city";
    paramname.Value = employee.City;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramcity);

    SqlParameter paramdateofbirth = new SqlParameter();
    paramdateofbirth.ParameterName = "@dateofbirth";
    paramname.Value = employee.Dateofbirth;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramdateofbirth);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
}
```

[my procedure code is given in snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Yht.jpg)

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

You are using the same `SqlParameter` object(`paramname`) which you used for Name for Gender and City. So it is basically overwriting the value with first Gender and then City. So i assume your `City` value is `null` hence it is throwing an error.

This should work

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spAddEmployee", con) {
                                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
    con.Open();
    var paramname = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@Name",
        Value = employee.Name
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramname);

    var paramgender = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@gender",
        Value = employee.Gender
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramgender);

    var paramcity = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@city",
        Value = employee.City
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramcity);

    var paramdateofbirth = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@dateofbirth",
        Value = employee.Dateofbirth
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramdateofbirth);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: Yes thanks for your help,now I can access to my stored procedure